# How do I set text color dynamically in a xamarin forms xaml page?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

Fairly new to Xamarin, I want to adjust the text color of a specific field in a grid based on some data from the model. I got the app to compile again with no errors but the text color of the field is not changing as I expect. Right now the logic is just trying to compare the quantity to a static value of 85 for testing purposes. There is 2 entries in my test data, one with a quantity of 50 and one with a quantity of 85. I am wondering if I am not looping over my data correctly and something is getting overwritten?

Here is my code thus far:

snip from xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"  TextColor="{Binding PartialQty_Format.Value, Converter={StaticResource IsPartialPalletBackgroundColor}}" Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RTIC.Scan.Converters
{
    internal class IsPartialPalletBackgroundColor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) == true ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:conveters="clr-namespace:RTIC.Scan.Converters"
             x:Class="RTIC.Scan.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <StyleSheetExtension Source="App.Styles.css" />
        <conveters:IsValidTextColor x:Key="IsValidTextColor"/>
        <conveters:IsFocusedBackgroundColor x:Key="IsFocusedBackgroundColor" />
        <conveters:IsPartialPalletBackgroundColor x:Key="IsPartialPalletBackgroundColor" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

View Model (see row with //handle PartialQty_Format property comment):

```
 public async Task LoadPallets()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SelectedDoorPage: LoadPallets(); invoked");
            try
            {
                var pallets = new List<Pallet>();
                string doorN = "0";
                int? apptKey = null;
                int? dockKey = null;

                if (validateDoorResponse.Value != null)
                {
                    doorN = doorNumber != null ? doorNumber : null;
                    apptKey = validateDoorResponse.Value != null ? validateDoorResponse.Value.AppointmentKey : null;
                }
                else
                {
                    dockKey = dockZone.Value.Id;
                }

                OutboundPallets = await _palletClient.GetOutboundPalletsForLoadingAsync(doorN, apptKey, dockKey);
                
                IEnumerable<OutboundPalletDTO> resultPallets;
                if (validateDoorResponse.Value != null)
                {
                    resultPallets = OutboundPallets.Pallets.Where(p => p.DoorId == doorNumber);
                } else
                {
                    resultPallets = OutboundPallets.Pallets;
                }

                //check to make sure there are not any pending load charges that needs to be processed
                if (await CheckForLoadCharges() == true)
                    return;

                //if there are no pallets to load then we can exit
                if (resultPallets == null || !resultPallets.Any())
                {
                    await DisplayToast(T("NoPalletsToLoad"), false);
                    await Task.Delay(2500);
                    await PopPage();
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var pallet in resultPallets)
                {
                    pallets.Add(new Pallet(pallet));
                }
                renderPallets(pallets);

                //handle PartialQty_Format property - djm 8/9/23
                foreach (var pallet in pallets)
                {           
                    if (pallet.Quantity != 85)
                    {
                        PartialQty_Format.Value = true;
                    };
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                _ = RaiseError(T("FailedToLoadPallets"), e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you debugged the converter?

Comment: @Jason, That is a good point. I just tried that and its not even hitting the converter... hmm

Comment: you might try defining the resource in the page instead

Comment: So there is another screen that has a "IsFocusedBackgroundColor" converter with very similar logic. I referenced my new converter on that other screen and it debugs/works just fine. Either I am not referencing this converter on the new screen correctly or not setting the property correctly?

Comment: What's the code of `PartialQty_Format`? Could you please post the full code of your viewmodel and `yourpage.xaml` ?

Comment: Where and how is `PartialQty_Format` defined and where do you call `LoadPallets()`?